# How to create a view to insert list of a type in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, view

I have a view in which a list of address details is to be save using form post. 
Its like :

[image]

How can I achieve this, I am not able to create view for it. I am using MVC 4, a view model.

Class for Communication detail

```
public class CommunicationDetail
{
    public int CommunicationDetailId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string STDCode { get; set; }
    public string Landline { get; set; }
}
```

List

```
public List<CommunicationDetail> CommunicationDetails { get; set; }
```

View :

```
@model AllCommunicationModels 
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.CommunicationDetails.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.CommunicationDetails[i].Email, new { @class = "inputValue" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.CommunicationDetails[i].MobileNumber, new { @class = "inputValue" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.CommunicationDetails[i].STDCode, new { @class = "inputValue" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.CommunicationDetails[i].Landline, new { @class = "inputValue" })
        </td>
        <td><span class="span-delete" data-model-id="@Model.Id" data-comm-id="@Model.CommunicationDetails[i].CommunicationDetailId" >x</span></td>
    </tr>
}
```

This action I want these data to be posted is this child method, I want to keep it separate
Child Action :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveCommDetail(AllCommunicationModels model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Json(new { Massage = "Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
    }
    return null });
}
```

But, it works only when I use parent viewModel as model of View.

```
public ActionResult Index(ParentViewModel model) {}
```

Comment: Did you create a view to accept list of `CommunicationDetail` as model? Tried using foreach Lolo there? Share the code you have written five this and tell us the exact problem you are facing.

Comment: Your issue is unclear. Are you trying to post an an array of objects to your controller ?  Or your requirement is something else ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am facing problem in creating view. Updating the view code in question

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV Yes, I am trying to post list of CommunicationDetail type to controller, that too on a spacific action, because this page is a partial view and I want its saving to be separate

Comment: I believe CommunicationDetail is your model class. If yes then add CommunicationDetails to your model then while posting u can get the data.

Comment: Yes, now i am getting data in list. But when, the partial view uses parent ViewModel which has ChildViewModel as property. The communicationDetail class is under childViewModel. How can I post that to child action